# Angular 2 open menu on click

Tags: angular, angular2-services

**header.component.html** have a button, when you click, menu mast show on in **users.component.html**. On click add class to button. How can I add class to menu block, when clicking on button in header (without jQuery)?

**header.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {GlobalService} from "../../global.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'header',
  providers: [GlobalService],
  templateUrl: 'app/_components/header/header.component.html'
})

export class HeaderComponent{

  public activeMobileMenuAdmin = false;
  public activeClass = false;

  constructor(public router: Router, public globalService: GlobalService){

    router.events.subscribe((val) => {

      if (val.url === '/login' || val.url === '/users') {
        this.adminPanelView = false;
      } else {
        this.adminPanelView = true;
      }

      if (val.url === '/users'){
        this.adminMenuView = true;
        this.detectDeviceWidth();
      } else {
        this.adminMenuView = false;
      }

    });

    this.activeClass = globalService.activeClass;

  }

  admMenuShow(){
    this.activeClass = !this.activeClass;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.detectDeviceWidth();
  }

  detectDeviceWidth() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
      this.activeMobileMenuAdmin = true;
    } else {
      this.activeMobileMenuAdmin = false;
    }
  }

}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<div class="menu-icon show-on-sm" [ngClass]="{'active': activeClass}" (click)="admMenuShow();" *ngIf="adminMenuView">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

**users.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {GlobalService} from "../../global.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'admin',
  providers: [GlobalService],
  templateUrl: 'app/admin/users/users.component.html'
})

export class AdminUsersComponent {
  private activeClass = true;
  constructor(public globalService: GlobalService){
    this.activeClass = globalService.activeClass;
  }
  admMenuShow(){
    this.activeClass = !this.activeClass;
  }
}
```

**users.component.html**

```
<div class="menu" id="admin-menu" [ngClass]="{'active': activeClass}">
<div class="contflex">
  <div class="h1">Test</div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active">List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**global.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {
  public user: Object = {};
  public hideMenu: boolean = true;
  public activeClass: boolean = false;

  constructor(public _router: Router) {}

  admMenuShow(){
    return this.activeClass = !this.activeClass;
  }

  onAuthError() {
    console.log('Works!');
  }
}
```

Page structure:

```
<header>
    ...
    <div class="menu-icon show-on-sm" [ngClass]="{'active': activeClass}" (click)="admMenuShow();" *ngIf="adminMenuView">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    ...
</header>
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <admin>
        ...
        <div class="menu" id="admin-menu" [ngClass]="{'active': activeClass}">
            <div class="contflex">
              <div class="h1">Menu</div>
              <ul>
                <li class="active">List 1</li>
                <li>List 2</li>
                <li>List 3</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        ...
    </admin>
</main>
```

This is [plunker project](https://plnkr.co/edit/z74Y7H)

This is [plunker result in full view](https://run.plnkr.co/TYA7ZgvYFwkBfjbl/)

Comment: what element do you mean by "menu block"?

Comment: can you create a working plunker ??

Answer (score 2):

First of all in `header.component.html` replace this line: 
`(click)="admMenuShow();"`

with 
`(click)="admMenuShow()"` , you dont need the semi-colon!

Secondly, I do not see that you have the class `active` in your header component (you called css class active in `[ngClass]="{'active': activeClass}"`. you may add it by adding `styles=['active: ...']` in header's component metadata.

As I understood, you have a header component and a user component, when you click a button in the header component, you want to apply a class to an element in the users component.

You can do this by using @Input decorator in your users component and then use binding as follows `<admin [ButtonSelected]="activeClass"></admin>` (`activeClass` is the boolean property of whatever component you are displaying the `<admin></admin>` in, in this case it is your header component)

For it to work, do not forget to import `Input` from `@angular/core` in your users component and use the decorator when you declare `ButtonSelected` boolean property, it will be: `@Input() ButtonSelected: boolean = false` instead of `ButtonSelected: boolean = false`; this way you will indicate to angular that the property `ButtonSelected` will be fed to users component by the "parent" component displaying it.

Here is a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z2j6WnEqqhxoewXJMw6F) (plunker I did not scratch, not yours)

EDITED:

I modified your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4VzV5R) to make it work, here it is. Note: view in full view mode to see the effect.

Comment: look my [link plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WcW8e0?p=preview) . My **header.component** is not a parent of **user.component** . I don't know how to watch to click on button in **header.component** .

Comment: i fix it.
This is [plunker project](https://plnkr.co/edit/z74Y7H)
This is [plunker result in full view](https://run.plnkr.co/TYA7ZgvYFwkBfjbl/)